# Several errors when trying to run the Pixel 2 Emulator on Ubuntu.

Tags: android-emulator

I followed the steps on this website (I am a beginner):

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

Here are the errors:

21:11   Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so

21:11   Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing

21:11   Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: r600

21:11   Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so

21:11   Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing

21:11   Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: r600

21:11   Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so

21:11   Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

21:11   Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

21:11   Emulator: Major opcode of failed request:  156 (GLX)

21:11   Emulator: Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)

21:11   Emulator: Value in failed request:  0x0

21:11   Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  64

21:11   Emulator: Current serial number in output stream:  65

21:11   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: /home/usuario/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_27.avd/userdata.img

21:11   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

The emulator I tried using was Pixel 2.
Thanks everyone!